# Como alternar entre o próximo elemento e o elemento anterior de um ListIterator com apenas um clique?

Tags: java, lista, iterator

Possuo uma lista de palavras armazenadas em minha variável `listaPalavra` já inicializada com valores, de tipo `ArrayList<T>`:

```
listaPalavra.add("Palavra 1");
listaPalavra.add("Palavra 2");
listaPalavra.add("Palavra 3");
listaPalavra.add("Palavra 4");
listaPalavra.add("Palavra 5");
```

desta lista de palavras eu obtenho a lista de itarator da seguinte forma:

```
listIterator = listaPalavra.listIterator();
```

Eu pretendo usar a minha lista de iterator `listIterator` para navegar nos elementos usando os métodos `next()` e `previous()` e exibi-los no formulário.

Este é o formulário:

[image: Formulario para nevegar nos entre os itens]

A navegação é feita pelos botões <kbd>Anterior</kbd> e <kbd>Proximo</kbd> da seguinte forma:

Rotina do botão <kbd>Anterior</kbd>:

```
private void btnAnteriorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
        lbValor.setText(listIterator.previous());
    }
}
```

Rotina do botão <kbd>Proximo</kbd>:

```
private void btnProximoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (listIterator.hasNext()) {
        lbValor.setText(listIterator.next());
    }        
}
```

Código completo do formulario que criei como exemplo para que seja reproduzido por vocês:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MainFrameExemplo extends javax.swing.JFrame {    
    List<String> listaPalavra = new ArrayList<>();        
    ListIterator<String> listIterator;
    
    public MainFrameExemplo() {
        initComponents();
        
        listaPalavra.add("Palavra 1");
        listaPalavra.add("Palavra 2");
        listaPalavra.add("Palavra 3");
        listaPalavra.add("Palavra 4");
        listaPalavra.add("Palavra 5");

        listIterator = listaPalavra.listIterator();
        
        String primeiroElemento = listaPalavra.get(0);
        
        lbValor.setText(primeiroElemento);
    }
        
    //Método para inicializar os componentes visuais, o NetBeans gera para você.        
    private void initComponents() {
    ...
    }

    private void btnAnteriorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        if (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
            lbValor.setText(listIterator.previous());
        }
    }                                           

    private void btnProximoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            lbValor.setText(listIterator.next());
        }        
    }                                          
        
    public static void main(String args[]) {                
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> 
        {
            new MainFrameExemplo().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
    
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAnterior;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnProximo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbValor;    
}
```

---

## Meu problema

Toda vez que eu vou alternar entre o próximo elemento e o elemento anterior eu **tenho que dar dois cliques no botão**, tanto quanto no botão <kbd>Proximo</kbd> como no botão <kbd>Anterior</kbd>. Eu gostaria de alternar entre os elementos próximo e anterior dando apenas um clique no botão.

Veja este gif que mostra o meu problema:

[image: Gif do problema]

Como eu poderiar solucionar este problema?

Comment: Duvida interessante essa, +1 :) depois leio a resposta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olá, meu jovem!

Cara, essa é uma dúvida mais fácil de explicar desenhando, mas vou tentar por texto.

O iterator tem como referência a lista em questão e também terá como referência o item atual. Quando você chega em algum dos extremos, como por exemplo no item "Palavra 5", ao dar um next, ele vai automaticamente para o item seguinte. Acontece que esse item não existe, mas o ponteiro de referência da lista movimentou-se. Por isso, quando você der um `listIterator.previous()` ele manterá o valor "Palavra 5", pois ele estava fora do range da lista, aí ele volta pro último item da lista.

O segredo pra corrigir  é verificar se você chegou em algum desses extremos e já "rebobinar" ou "avançar" pro item da extremidade.

```
private void btnAnteriorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    if (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
        String previous = listIterator.previous();
        lbValor.setText(previous);
        if ( !listIterator.hasPrevious()  ) listIterator.next();
    }
}                                           

private void btnProximoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if ( listIterator.hasNext()  ) {
        lbValor.setText(listIterator.next());
        if ( !listIterator.hasNext()  ) listIterator.previous();
    }        
}
```

Outra alteração é no momento que o frame é instanciado. Nele você tá pegando o item 0 do vetor. O legal é que você já passe a usar o próprio iterator:

```
    listIterator = listaPalavra.listIterator();
    String primeiroElemento = listIterator.next();
    lbValor.setText(primeiroElemento);
```

Saudações!

**Edição 01**

Após colocar a gif, notou-se que era preciso tomar outra direção e usar o índice para acessar a mensagem.

No main, é melhor usar assim

```
   listIterator = listaPalavra.listIterator();
   listIterator.next();
   String primeiroElemento = listaPalavra.get(listIterator.nextIndex() - 1);
   lbValor.setText(primeiroElemento);
```

E nos listiners assim:

```
private void btnAnteriorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    if (listIterator.hasPrevious() && listIterator.previousIndex() > 0) {
        listIterator.previous();
        lbValor.setText( listaPalavra.get(listIterator.nextIndex() - 1) );
    }
}                                           

private void btnProximoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if ( listIterator.hasNext()  ) {
        listIterator.next();
        lbValor.setText( listaPalavra.get(listIterator.nextIndex() - 1) );
    }        

}
```

Comment: Ola, a questão da borda funcionou, porem, se eu tiver na `palavra 3` e quiser voltar para o anterior que e a `palavra 2` tenho q clicar duas vezes no botão Anterior.

Comment: Sério? Estranho cara, na minha implementação aqui foi de boa. 
Dá uma olhada: http://dev.coppieters.com.br/exemplos/MainFrameExemplo.java

Comment: Sim, eu usei a sua implementação, quando eu vou clicar no proximo e depois em seguida clico em Anterior ele nao muda, tenho q clicar novamente no anterior para mudar o valor.

Comment: Botei um gif na pergunta.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho, cara eu coloquei a seguinte linha nos dois caras que tratam o evento:  System.out.println("Próximo indice:" + listIterator.nextIndex() + " - Indice anterior:" + listIterator.previousIndex() );
 Quando muda a direção do vetor, parece que ele se perde pra retornar o valor, mas não o indice. 
Ao trocar pra pegar o indice, e colocando uma validação prévia no rebobinar, passa funcionar.
Dá uma olhada no link d'outro cometário.

Comment: Funcionou aqui :D